# Prove or disprove the convergence of $\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}\frac{n^{2}+n+\sin n}{3n^{3}+n+7}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know that the series $\sum\limits ^{\infty }_{n=1}\dfrac{1}{n}$ diverges, so I tried to use it in order to prove that the above series also diverges.

I did the following.

$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{n^2+n+\sin n}{3n^3+n+7}\geq \sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{n^2}{11n^3}=\frac{1}{11}\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{1}{n}$$

And then proved the divergence of series $\dfrac{1}{11}\sum\limits^\infty_{n=1}\dfrac{1}{n}$

Is this a correct approach to the following problem?

Comment: I'm confused. Your title mentions the Cauchy criterion, but you did not use it. Are you supposed to use it or not?

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: I used Cauchy criterion to prove that the bottom series diverges and since it diverges then we can say that above series also diverge. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, your solution is correct.

Comment: Good. Another variant of this technique is that if $A_n$ is the $n$th term of your series then $\frac {A_n}{1/n}=\frac {1+n^{-1}+n^{-2}\sin n}{3+n^{-2}+7n^{-3}}\to 1/3$ as $n\to\infty$, so for all but finitely many $n$ we have $\frac {A_n}{1/n}>1/4.$

Answer (score 1):

The numerator

$$n^2+n+\sin(n)=n^2(1+\frac 1n+\frac{\sin(n)}{n^2})$$
$$=n^2(1+\epsilon_1(n))\sim n^2$$

the denominator

$$3n^3+n+7=3n^3(1+\frac{1}{3n^2}+\frac{7}{3n^3})$$
$$=3n^3(1+\epsilon_2(n))\sim 3n^3$$

So

$$\frac{n^2+n+\sin(n)}{3n^3+n+7}\sim \frac{n^2}{3n^3}\sim \frac{1}{3n}$$

thus the series is divergent.